# Insert multiple lines of json in DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following json file

```
{"columnwithoutname":"structureet","nofinesset":810001792,"nofinessej":810001784}
{"columnwithoutname":"structureet","nofinesset":670797117,"nofinessej":670010339}
```

I want to insert it in DynamoDB using Lambda. This is what I did:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket=event['b']
    file_key=event['c']
    table=event['t']
    recList=[]
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
    obj= s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file_key)
    recList=obj['Body'].read().split('\n')
    for row in recList:
        response = dynamodb.put_item(TableName='test-abe', Item=row)
```

But I have this error:

```
 "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Item
```

Apparently I also need to precise the type of each column so it could be accepted. Anyway to do it automatically? I want all columns to be strings. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB client expects `Item` parameter to be a `dict` (per https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item)

When you do `recList = obj['Body'].read().split('\n')` what you get is a list of `str`, so passing `str` to a param expecting `dict` will obviously fail.

One more thing to consider is that DynamoDB **client** expects item in a very specific format, with explicitly specified attribute datatypes. If you want to read JSON and simply write it, I suggest using DynamoDB **resource**, something like this:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
table.put_item(item)
```

`Table.put_item()` accepts simple `dict` with no need to specify data type for every attribute, so you can simply read from file, convert it to dict and send it away (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.put_item).

Comment: Thank you. Can I just convert my json rows to dict and insert them using table.put_item?

Comment: @Haha generally that should be enough. You can use `json.loads(row)` to load json into dict and test it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manipulate each row in order to have the 'S' format:

```
import json

for row in recList:
    row_dict = json.loads(row)
    ddb_row_dict = {k:{"S": v} for (k,v) in row_dict.items()}
    response = dynamodb.put_item(TableName='test-abe', Item=ddb_row_dict)
```